# Clicking on sub menu not opening the page it is hiding the sub menu in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi i have created a dropdown sidebar menu but the problem when i click on main menu it is displaying the sub menu correctly but the problem is when i click on sub menu it is not opening the link it is getting hided.Here is the code for that.

```
<aside id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <div class="sidebar-brand">
              <h2>Materno Platform</h2>
            </div>
            <ul class="sidebar-nav">
                <li><a href="index.html">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Customers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">providers</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">User Management</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Plans</a></li>
                <li class="has-ul"><a href="#">Order Fullfillment<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                  <ul class="sub-ul">
                    <li><a href="#">Plan Purchases</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Med Orders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lab Orders</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">predictive Analytics</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="has-ul"><a href="#">Master Data Management<i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                  <ul class="sub-ul">
                    <li><a href="careplans.html">Care Plans</a></li>            
                  </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Transcriptions</a></li>
                <li><a href="profile.html">Profile</a></li>         
            </ul>
        </aside>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $("#sidebar-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
  });
  $('li.has-ul').click(function() {
  $(this).children('.sub-ul').slideToggle(500);
  $(this).toggleClass('active');
  event.preventDefault();
  });
```

Fiddle Link: https://jsfiddle.net/3yfdcto0/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Jquery

```
$('li.has-ul a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('.sub-ul').slideToggle(500);
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  /*event.preventDefault();*/
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lalji1051/kp8x4e7w/4/

Comment: If i click on that sub menu it is not redirecting to that particular URL

Comment: remove this line `event.preventDefault();`

Comment: @tester Have you checked that you have an url in it. because all your links except the first looks like `href="#"`, so that might be why it dont redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you.

```
$('li.has-ul a').click(function() {
  $(this).siblings('.sub-ul').slideToggle(500);
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('active');
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Clicking on that not redirecting to that URL

Comment: remove this $(this).children('.sub-ul').slideToggle(500);